# Not able to start docker-mongo service

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-swarm, docker-container, docker-image

I am using docker version-3.
Once I deploy a stack all services are up except for mongo service.

This is how I setup mongo:

```
1. docker build -t pr-db https://github.com/docker-library/mongo.git#:4.1
2. docker tag pr-db uday0docker/pr-db:init
3. docker swarm init
4. docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml pr
```

I have 4 services,3 of them are up except for `pr-db`.

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                      PORTS
6c1vxzqjbfkk        pr_backend          replicated          1/1                 backend:latest

98ohsig17y2l        pr_balancer         replicated          1/1                 balancer:latest            *:80->80/tcp

u3mslb35b3f5        pr_db               replicated          0/1                 uday0docker/pr-db:latest

b0a3k0gz6yzs        pr_frontend         replicated          1/1                 frontend:latest
```

My local mongo is down.

When I ran `docker service logs u3mslb35b3f5` its empty.

If I stop the stack and only run `docker run -p 27017:27017 pr-db` the container is up, I'm not able to run it in swarm mode.

How do we debug this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `docker service ps pr_db`? this should list the service tasks running or failing for this service

Comment: @nadavbrkt, Thanks for the help `docker service ps pr_db` revealed that a folder was expected and it didn start because of that.

Comment: provide compose file for more clarity.

Comment: @Mani, Solved the problem!